# <head> element inside xsl:template ignored, XML, XSL, XHTML

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I have a weird problem with `head` element being ignored inside `<xsl:template>` element:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- 
strict.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./design.css" type="text/css"/>
        <title>XML Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">Some text</header>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Chrome/Mozilla result: title element is written inside body element, not as tab title as it should be. Also the .css is ignored.

What could the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/xhtml` is not the XHTML namespace, if you really want to create XHTML then use the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.

Of course it is not clear how you run the XSLT and whether the browser sees the XSLT result as text/html or as application/xml or any other XML media type, but fixing the namespace would be the first step to have XHTML elements be recognized and used with the semantics you expect.